# Screensaver suddenly active

Tags: macos, preferences, screensaver

I've always opted to have my display turn off after *X* amount of time in lieu of using a screensaver.  My screensaver preferences were set to **`Start after: Never`**. That is until today.  I walked into the room and noticed the screensaver running.  When I went to check the system preferences it was set to **`20 minutes`**.

- I did not set it to 20 minutes.
- No one else ever uses this computer
- I haven't done any updates to my OS recently

This strikes me as pretty odd.  Anyone have a possible explanation?  Might there be a historical record of when and how this change happened in a log somewhere?

I am running 10.11.3.

Comment: Have you tried a 'Repair Permissions'?

Comment: @CousinCocaine - can you be more specific?  Are you suggesting that repairing permissions might have caused my preferences settings to change?

Comment: Yep. Your permissions haven't changed after setting them. It might be due to file rights.

Comment: but what would cause it to suddenly change to `20 minutes`?  I've had it on `Never` for years and it's never been touched and always worked as expected in the past.  The thing I'm trying to understand is what would cause my prefs to suddenly change?  I haven't done anything to the permissions.

Comment: strange indeed. As if the settings are back to there default state. Sorry, but I have no clue why.